# ubuntu phone SO dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, backup

A few months ago I bought meizu Pro 5 (ubuntu edition) and I need whatsapp among other android apps.
It is possible to make a dualboot or if unable to do so, as it could make a copy of the entire device to temporarily install android?

pd: sorry for my engish